# Linq genera instrucción SQL errónea para MySQL

Tags: mysql, c#, entity-framework, linq, visual-studio-2019

Estoy trabajando en una aplicación web con VisualStudio 2019 c#, la BD creada solo para probar la conexión está en MySQL en una máquina virtual, la generación del modelo emdx está lista al igual que la cadena de conexión, el problema es que hasta ahora no he logrado hacer una consulta a la BD ya que se genera una excepción de que la tabla no existe pues la consulta que se está mandando deja junto el nombre de la BD y la tabla que quiero consultar (dentro de una sola comilla) y está buscando una tabla con el nombre "BD.tabla" y no "BD"."Tabla".

```
conn = new ConnectionEntities();

lstPlanes = (from p in conn.Plan
             where p.id_Plan > 1
             select p).ToList();
```

Al navegar por el objeto de conexión aparece la consulta así:

```
SELECT `Extent1`.`id_Plan`, `Extent1`.`nombre`, `Extent1`.`descripcion`, `Extent1`.`costoMensualidad` FROM `BD_GYM_Mysql.Plan` AS `Extent1`
```

Y en la excepción interna marca lo siguiente:

```
{"Table 'BD_GYM_Mysql.BD_GYM_Mysql.Plan' doesn't exist"}
```

Estas son las versiones y elementos que estoy usando:

- VisualStudio 2019
- EntityFramework 6.4.4
- MySQL Connector 8.0.23
- MySQL for VisualStudio 1.2.9

Si alguien pudiera ayudarme diciéndome si hay algo mal o me falta algo se los agradecería mucho.

Comment: cómo está tu entityConfiguration? es code first?